# Form that completes Values in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a normal form in a PHP page, I send data to the php page from another for using POST. The PHP page runs some scripts to update data to SQL but on that page I have a second form that needs to be completed with data from the initial form prior to updating the SQL.

```
 $recipient_nr = $_REQUEST['recipient_nr'];
```

Here I draw the info from the first form

Now I want to use this in a new form on the current PHP page how do I state this in the new form

```
 <input type="text" name="recipient_nr" id="recipient_nr" value=".$recipient_nr.">
```

This is what I am attempting but it is not working I know I have too many "'" xxx"'" in the lines but not sure how to remidy this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you generate the new form in PHP? If so, where is the code where you do that?

If this is some kind of `...?> <input type="..."...> <?php ...` page generation then you'll need to echo that `$recipient_nr` into the PHP-generated response:

```
...
?>
<input type="text"
       name="recipient_nr"
       id="recipient_nr"
       value="<?php echo $recipient_nr; ?>">
<?php
...
```

Or, if you have short echos turned on,

```
...
?>
<input type="text"
       name="recipient_nr"
       id="recipient_nr"
       value="<?= $recipient_nr ?>">
<?php
...
```

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about echo'ing the info it worked will tick you soon as i can

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 <input type="text" name="recipient_nr" id="recipient_nr" value="<?php echo $recipient_nr; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$recipient_nr = array_key_exists('recipient_nr', $_REQUEST)
    ? (string) $_REQUEST['recipient_nr']
    : 'default value or empty string';
```

And output it:

```
<input type="text"
        name="recipient_nr"
        id="recipient_nr"
        value="<?=$recipient_nr?>">
```

But if you want store this data for/between other pages you can use $_SESSION global array for save it.